# Validation of viewstate MAC failed with server.transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, webforms

I've done some googling on this and i know a question similar to this has been asked several times, but so far I'm not having any luck.

I've got the home page on our site also set up to be the 404/410 error page. When I do a `server.transfer` to this page the search form on the page no longer works. `Response.redirect` to this page and it works fine.

So in my code the page doing the server transfer has

`Server.Transfer("/default.aspx?status=410", false);`

When i then use the search form on `default.aspx` after getting there from the transfer, i get the error in the title.

I also see that the action value on the form has a value, whereas normally it should be blank.  I saw another post suggesting setting this value manually in my content page, but I would have to hardcode the ID for the form and I'm not sure if that would cause issues on other pages since this form is used by all the pages on the site since this master page is the main master page for the whole site. Plus even when i did hard code the ID and then used `Page.Master.Findcontrol` to get the form and set Action = "" it still had a value set for action instead of an empty string.

I had thought as long as I didn't use `Server.Transfer("", true)` I shouldn't get this error. And i do have a machineKey entry in my web.config

Anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.Transfer()
```

and `Response.Redirect()`

both are performing same functionality like help to navigate user from one page to another, but internal process happening inside system little bit different. To get more idea about that please visit 
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/csharp/c4SE281212-Difference-between-Response.Redirect-and-Server.Transfer.html

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. I understand the difference between Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect. I'm trying to find out how to use Server.Transfer to redirect a user to another page. I do NOT want to use Response.Redirect. If you have any ideas how to do use Server.Transfer and not get the viewstate mac failed when i submit the form on the page that's being transferred too, i'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution, although I'd appreciate some feedback to explain something.

On the page that's being transferred to (default.aspx) I tried using Form.Action = "" and when i loaded the page that resulted in the action being something like action="/../../../default.aspx"

Just now i tried it again but I used Form.Action = "/", which did set the action to "/" and that seems to work.

So i guess my question is why did trying to set the action to "" result in that relative url?
And is this the correct way to handle this problem?

Thanks